# Infinite loop with do-while condition

Tags: java, do-while

i'm doing an easy exercise for school, everything work except for this method. i want to insert some teams in a vector, but the array "serie" can only be A or B, upper or lower. I check with the debug and the while condition doens't work even if serie[i]=a.

```
public static void popolamento(String squadre[], char serie[], int punti[]) {
  Scanner in= new Scanner(System.in);
  for (int i=0;i<punti.length;i++) {
      System.out.println("How many teams?");
      squadre[i]=in.next();
      do {
          serie[i]=in.next().charAt(0);
          System.out.println(serie[i]);
      }
      while (serie[i]!='a' || serie[i]!='A' || serie[i]!='b' || serie[i]!='B');
  punti[i]=in.nextInt();

  }
  System.out.println("teams entered correctly ");}
```

Comment: `||` means that if _any_ condition is true, the entire statement is true. You want `&&`.

Comment: I suggest you think about your logic: `while (serie[i]!='a' || serie[i]!='A' ...` – Ask yourself out loud: what does it say?

Answer (score 1):

The condition

```
 (X != a || X != b || X != c || X != d)
```

should have been

```
 (X != a && X != b && X != c && X != d)
```

Such a *pattern* is very likely an error, as to fail, all terms must fail
When X == u (X != u fails) then X != v holds (different cases assumed), hence always true.

If you read something like this, you know it is in 99.9% an error.

Comment: Thank you, it work! i used the || for a similar condition in another exercise and worked, I misread the exit condition for the do-while!